# Save a csv like string into Django model

Tags: python, django

I need to save an amazon response in to mysql db (Django)
Here is the example response

```
         id                   purchase-date               last-updated-date        status   
         305-0847312-2761164      2022-04-11T22:23:27+00:00   2022-04-11T22:23:31+00:00  Pending    
         028-3270261-2897162      2022-04-11T22:17:27+00:00   2022-04-11T22:17:30+00:00  Pending    
         028-8245400-1649940      2022-04-11T22:15:29+00:00   2022-04-11T22:15:32+00:00  Pending    
         028-2661715-2120359      2022-04-11T21:57:24+00:00   2022-04-11T21:57:28+00:00  Pending    
         303-9076983-4225163      2022-04-11T21:53:52+00:00   2022-04-11T21:53:55+00:00  Pending    
         304-7440363-0208337      2022-04-11T21:49:14+00:00   2022-04-11T21:49:17+00:00  Pending    
         302-2070657-8345128      2022-04-11T21:30:12+00:00   2022-04-12T01:32:20+00:00  Shipped
```

Each header( id,                      purchase-date,                  last-updated-date,           status   ) represents a field in a table, I tried the following code

```
          reader = csv.DictReader(res.payload.get("document"))
          for row in reader:
              Mytable.Objects.create(field_id=id, **row)
```

Any Idea to achieve this?

Regards

Update. It would be much easier if the reponse can be as comman separeted csv file, something like

```
   id,  purchase-date,               updated-date
   000, 2022-04-11T22:23:27+00:00, ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
      reader = csv.DictReader(res.payload.get("document"))
      for row in reader:
          item = dict(row)
          _id = item.pop("id")
          Mytable.Objects.create(field_id=_id, defaults=item)
```

- The names of the fields of the model must correspond.
  But without the model of your database I can't help you anymore.